# Physics bodies for irregular shapes in spritekit

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have made the following code for one of my physics bodies:

```m
    CGFloat offsetX = ship.frame.size.width * ship.anchorPoint.x;
    CGFloat offsetY = ship.frame.size.height * ship.anchorPoint.y;

    CGMutablePathRef path2 = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path2, NULL, 10 - offsetX, 1 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path2, NULL, 8 - offsetX, 12 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path2, NULL, 10 - offsetX, 14 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path2, NULL, 10 - offsetX, 37 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path2, NULL, 5 - offsetX, 44 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path2, NULL, 0 - offsetX, 36 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path2, NULL, 0 - offsetX, 16 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path2, NULL, 2 - offsetX, 11 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path2, NULL, 0 - offsetX, 1 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path2, NULL, 0 - offsetX, 0 - offsetY);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path2, NULL, 10 - offsetX, 0 - offsetY);

    CGPathCloseSubpath(path2);

    ship.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path2];
```

It seems fine to me but whenever I run it I get an error that says: "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT".
Does anyone see anything wrong with my code or know why this wouldn't be working?
If you need me to specify anything just ask and I'll be glad to.

Comment: Learn how to use UIBezierPath.

Comment: polygon must be convex, and points in counterclockwise order

Answer (score 2):

I get the following error with your code:

Assertion failed: (area > 1.19209290e-7F), function ComputeCentroid, file /SourceCache/PhysicsKit/PhysicsKit-6.5.4/PhysicsKit/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2PolygonShape.cpp, line 122.

The following little code snippet will draw the outline over your sprite:

```m
        SKShapeNode *outline = [SKShapeNode node];
        outline.name = @"outline";
        outline.path = path2;
        [outline setLineWidth:0.5];
        [outline setStrokeColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
        [self addChild:outline];
```

And the error is clear: your polygon outline is not convex, it goes in & out at the tail of the missile shape.

A quick google will explain what convex means if you don't know:
http://www.mathopenref.com/polygonconvex.html

A more interesting approach which I've taken in my own app is to automatically generate the physics outline from the image bitmap.

This is too complex to post in detail here, but the algorithm works as follows:

- Generate points along the outline of the bitmap (I do this by tracing rays from the outside to the centre to find the furthest point out in any given direction).
- Enumerate through the points and remove any that are below minimum distance from the line segment defined by its two neighbouring points.
- Remove any non-convex points (i.e.: if the segments bends to the right, use a dot product)
- Increase the tolerance and iterate till we have less than 12 points (or whatever your max is).

This has the great advantage that once you've coded it, you can completely forget about defining polygonal outlines for your graphics and they're just computed on the fly in milliseconds.